# Where is this repository prompt coming from in new juno install?

Tags: eclipse-juno

I just reinstalled Eclipse Juno.  I've had many eclipse installations over the years, but I thought this was a fresh one.  Obviously not that fresh.  This window keeps prompting me for a login.  The hostname it's listing as a repository is no longer used for anything, but it might have been an old subversion repository. I've combed through all the preferences and can't find anything that might be doing this.

One hint is that a change I made to a file to eliminate a compile error did not "take".  The offending line is gone, but the error won't go away. It acts like the file did not get changed after all.  Maybe related -- maybe not.

Where is this coming from?  How do I stop it from prompting me?  I have to hit cancel 3 times before it goes away.  It recurs with agonizing fury when I try to close a project.  This is driving me crazy.

I installed a recent version of JBOss Tools along with this. Jboss Dev Studio 6.0.1 which contains jboss tools 3.4.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andre and I discussed this a bit more over on https://community.jboss.org/message/821239 and we concluded this is related to my version control.  The host mentioned in the prompt is our former SVN repository.

I never did find anything untoward configured on my project, but I probably missed it and in the meantime re-installed everything, reimported the projects and the problem went away.

I have since upgraded to JBDS 7 and the problem hasn't recured yet, but then again I didn't yet install subclipse.  I've just done that 5 min ago.  If the problem recurs, I will hunt for answers in the project Team->SVN preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sure that you have some preferences settings for a proxy in Eclipse (Window->Preferences->Proxy). Assuming that you dont need a proxy then clearing those will prevent this dialog from popping up. 
If you need a proxy then things get more complicated. A bad design in the JDK, a very lacking default proxy plugin and several competing fixes cause Eclipse to behave differently depending on the plugins you have. The dialog you screenshotted is caused by the default Eclipse proxy support in org.eclipse.ui.net. It's limitations are very well known but none fixed those in the platform yet:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=196780

This very lacking plugin is overriden by EGit, Scout and others. Depending on which of these plugins you have, you will or wont get the above dialog. The best advice I can give you is to make sure that you have EGit installed (and make sure it's started: have some git shared projects in your workspace or open the "Git Repository Exploring" perspective" at least once). EGit overrides the default proxy plugin by a far superior plugin that prevents the above dialog from appearing.

If you need more details, the you can have a look at a very similar issue we ran into in OpenShift/JBoss Tools. The jira issue holds all informations and insights I collected when looking into this weirdness:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-12999

Cheers
André